# get sql result as nested json object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

Using sql query with group_concat through a while loop, I achieved the result below:

```
$rows[] = array('name' =>$row['customer'] , 'atw' =>$row['atw_number'] ,
     'dr' =>array(array('drnumber'=>(($row['dr_number'])),)),);
```

**{
      "name": "MULTIBUILD CORP",
      "atw": "7146",
      "dr": [
        {
          "drnumber": "1608,1610,1611"
        }
      ]
    },**

instead, can i have something like:

**{
      "name": "MULTIBUILD CORP",
      "atw": "7146",
      "dr": [
        {
          "drnumber": "1608"
        },
        {
          "drnumber": "1610"
        },
        {
        "drnumber": "1611"
        }
      ]
    },**

Comment: You will have to create a php script like that. I mean you will have to do it manually using some loops. That wil do it

Comment: What SQL Database are you using?

Comment: hey bud, its mysql..

Comment: yeah thanks for the info pritesh..
 
You will have to create a php script like that. I mean you will have to do it manually using some loops. That wil do it – pritesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your while loop replace your current `$rows[] = ...` with:

```
$numbers = [];
foreach (explode(',', $row['dr_number']) as $number)
    $numbers[] = ['dr_number' => $number];

$rows[] = array(
    'name' => $row['customer'],
    'atw' => $row['atw_number'],
    'dr' => $numbers
);
```